# Difference between _sql_constraints and _constraints on OpenERP/Odoo?

Tags: python, constraints, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I noticed there are 2 kinds of constraints on Odoo ERP.
But I want to know what is the difference between _sql_constraints vs _constraints?

```
_sql_constraints = {
    ('email_uniq', 'unique(email)', ' Please enter Unique Email id.')
}

_constraints=[
    (_check_qty_and_unitprice, u'Qty must be more than 0',['product_qty', 'cost_unit']),
]
```

Answer (score 9):

`_sql_constraints` means it will set constraint on postgresql database side.

```
_sql_constraints = [
     ('email_uniq', 'unique(email)', ' Please enter Unique Email id.'),
     ]
```

Where:

- `email_uniq` means constraint name,
- `unique(email)` means `unique` is name of constraint. `email` is a field name which constraint will apply on that field.
- `'Please enter Unique Email id.'` is a message and it will display on pop-up window when constraint would be violated.

`_constraints` is python constraint. We can give our logic to set constraints. For example:

```
_constraints = [
     (_check_qty_and_unitprice, u'Qty must be more than 0', ['product_qty', 'cost_unit']),
     ]
```

Where :

- `_check_qty_and_unitprice` is a function name where we need to apply our logic.
- `'Qty must be more than 0'` is a message and it will display on pop-up window when constraint would be violated (the python function returns `False`).
- `['product_qty', 'cost_unit']` is a list of field name which means constraint will fire for these two fields.

As of the new **Odoo API** `python constraint` have a **new and simpler** decorator. The below example can be written like this:

```
from openerp.exceptions import ValidationError

@api.constraints('product_qty', 'cost_unit')
def _check_something(self):
    for record in self:
        if record.product_qty < 1:
            raise ValidationError("Qty must be more than 0")
```