# Can I enforce unique Account for partner?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

We have Account Numbers and list of partner (Customers and/or Vendors) in journal entry we have some account that have unique partner and other none

We are finding users entering Customers and/or Vendors into Odoo  in account that not have partner - they are not checking properly before adding the information in invoice move line.

How can we build a check into Odoo so that the same Customer and/or Vendor doesn't get created for this account

```
 EX: 
  401111 -> partner (BNA) -> in move line can add partner (BNA)

  700000-> doesn't have partner ->in move line disable.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please update your question with attempted code, any tracebacks, current output, expected output.

Comment: i try use an model in odoo app account_partner_required they give policy to account if nerver disable if always enable

Comment: You can use sql unique constrains to achieve it. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736799/difference-between-sql-constraints-and-constraints-on-openerp-odoo/31738033